# How to display total value of Price column in ASP.NET Core web app

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an `Index.cshtml` page using Razor Pages and a `Data.js` file used to retrieve data. Now I have got the data but now I want to display the total Price column.

Markup and code in `Index.cshtml`:

```
<div class="x_content">
    <table class="table table-hover" id="tblProduct">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Sum:</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var js = jQuery.noConflict(true);

    js('#tblProduct').dataTable({
        "footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {
            var api = this.api(),
                data;

            var intVal = function (i) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$a-zA-Z, ]/g, '') * 1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };

            var cols = [1];

            for (let index = 0; index < cols.length; index++) {
                var col_data = cols[index];
                total = api
                    .column(col_data)
                    .data()
                    .reduce(function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0);

                // Update footer
                js(api.column(col_data).footer()).html(
                    total
                );
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Code load from `Data.js`:

```
function BindProductsToGrid(products) {
    $('#tblProduct tbody').empty();

    var tr;
    $.each(products, function (index, product) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append(`<td>${(index + 1)}</td>`);
        tr.append(`<td>${product.name}</td>`);
        tr.append(`<td>${product.category}</td>`);
        tr.append(`<td>${product.price}</td>`);
        $('#tblProduct').append(tr);
    });
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot displayed after loading data]

I use ASP.NET Core 6 web app.

Answer (score 0):

According to your codes, you used the wrong column index which makes the callback function doesn't calculate the right price.

To solve the issue and show the sum as your image shown,you could refer to below codes:

Firstly modify the tfoot to add 4 th.

```
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Sum:</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

Then modify the jquery to calculate the right column.

```
<script>
    var js = jQuery.noConflict(true);

    js('#tblProduct').dataTable({
        "footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {
            var api = this.api(),
                data;

            var intVal = function (i) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$a-zA-Z, ]/g, '') * 1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };

            var col_data = 3; // Use the correct index for the "Price" column

            total = api
                .column(col_data)
                .data()
                .reduce(function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0);

            // Update footer for the "Price" column
            js(api.column(col_data).footer()).html(
                total 
            );
        }
    });

</script>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did it, embed the code below. Thank you everyone for your interest.

```
function addTotalRow() {
var total = 0;
$('#tblProduct tr:not(:first) td:nth-of-type(4)').each(function () {
    total += +$(this).text();
});
$('#tblProduct').append('<tfoot><tr><th>Sum:</th><th></th><th></th><th>' + total + '</th></tr></tfoot> ');
```

}